# Percentage difference between the values that matches the year

Tags: python, list, zip, percentage

```
year = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
value1 = [5674, 5647, 4327, 8654]
```

How I display the percentage difference between each values in the 'value1' list that corresponds the 'year' list

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that is what you need, the formula for the percentage difference is based on this [online calculator](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/percent-difference-calculator.php#:%7E:text=Percentage%20Difference%20Formula%3A,numbers%2C%20all%20multiplied%20by%20100.)

```
def percentage_difference(num1, num2):
  return abs(num1 - num2) * 100 / ((num1 + num2) / 2.0)

years = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018] 
values = [5674, 5647, 4327, 8654]
percentage_differences = [percentage_difference(year, value) for year, value in zip(years, values)]

print(percentage_differences)
```

Which produces an output of `[95.17492521784368, 94.76706250815607, 72.82471626733921, 124.36281859070463]` for the sample values you have provided